# (Java) How to parse a coordinate string with multiple possible formats, and convert them into ints?

Tags: java, string, parsing, format, coordinates

I have a method which takes in (X,Y) coordinate strings from the user. Both the X and Y coordinates range from 0 to 8, and the coordinates can be one of the five possible formats:

- **(4,3)**: X and Y coordinates in parenthesis, and separated by comma and no space
- **4  3**: X and Y coordinate separated by space only, no parenthesis
- **4,3**: X and Y coordinate separated by comma only, no parenthesis
- **d  3**: X represented by letters. 0=A, 1=B, ..., 8=H. X and Y separated by space
- **d3**: Same as above except no space.

What I am having trouble with is developing a single method which can successfully parse all four formats. More specifically, I want to successfully convert both the X and Y coordinates into two separate ints and store them somewhere, regardless of which format is used.

I am somewhat new to java, and do not have much experience parsing strings. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets consider a master format. A format we want to convert all of these to, in order to finally convert them into two ints. Let's make this format two numbers separated by a space. This is IMO the easiest to parse.

Then, let's consider the patterns these all share. For example, the first input is guarrenteed to only have a parentheses, so we can recognise that easily. The third is guarrenteed to contain a comma, but no parentheses. So, we can group these with a rule, if it has a comma, remove parentheses if there are any and replace the comma with a space.

That's three down, 2 to go.

Now, whats common with these last two? They share a letter. We can easily catch this letter with regex, but let's worry about that later. So, let's make a logical rule.

If, the phrase didn't have a comma,
     we check if it has a letter. If so, we check if it has a space.
           If so, we split by the space, and replace the character with its integer equilavent, offset correctly to represent its position in the alphabet. 
           Otherwise, we split by the letter using regex, and perform the above.

Now we got a clear image in our mind of what we want to achomplish, let's try do it ourselves.

This is how I would do it in code.

```
  public int[] parseXYCoord(String s) {
    String master=s;
    if(s.contains(",")){
        master=master.replace("(","").replace(")","");
        master=master.replace(","," ");
    }else if(master.matches("^[a-z]((\\s[0-8])|[0-8])$")){
        int charValue=master.charAt(0)-'a'+1;
        master=charValue+" "+master.charAt(master.contains(" ")?2:1);


    }
    return parseMaster(master);
}

private int[] parseMaster(String master) {
    if(!master.matches("^[0-8] [0-8]$"))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Inputted Number is incorrect!");
    String[] splitMaster=master.split(" ");
    return new int[]{Integer.parseInt(splitMaster[0]),Integer.parseInt(splitMaster[1])};

}
```

I'm not too good at regex. While it is ugly, it does get the job done. Check out the site [DebugRegex](https://www.debuggex.com/) if you want to learn how to use regex.

Testing it using

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseXYCoord("4,3")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseXYCoord("4 3")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseXYCoord("(4,3)")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseXYCoord("d3")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseXYCoord("d 3")));
```

It prints

```
[4, 3]
[4, 3]
[4, 3]
[4, 3]
[4, 3]
```

Comment: Appreciate the explanation, and the introduction to regex. Like I said, I'm fairly new, and have not come across that concept yet. That was the kind of pointer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Pizza I'm glad you found it easy to understand. If need help with any concepts from the above, let me know and I would be happy to help out. If you feel that you understand the above well and can guarrentee you will not switch to double digits anytime soon, I recommend azro's answer which harnesses the power of regex and java 8 in order to do it in one clean method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as steps :

- remove all characters that are not digits or letters, you'll end with 2 chars sticked
- look each of the two :

  - if digit  : parse to `int`
  - if not remove char code `'a'` and add `+1` to get *a=1, b=2, ...*

```
private static int[] parseToCoord(String s) {
    String[] xy = s.replaceAll("[^\\w\\d]", "").toLowerCase().split("");
    int[] res = new int[2];
    res[0] = xy[0].matches("\\d") ? Integer.parseInt(xy[0]) : xy[0].charAt(0) - 'a' + 1;
    res[1] = xy[1].matches("\\d") ? Integer.parseInt(xy[1]) : xy[1].charAt(0) - 'a' + 1;
    return res;
}
```

The `Stream` version is

```
private static int[] parseToCoordStream(String s) {
    return Stream.of(s.replaceAll("[^\\w\\d]", "").toLowerCase().split(""))
            .mapToInt(val -> val.matches("\\d") ? Integer.parseInt(val) : val.charAt(0) - 'a' + 1)
            .toArray();
}
```

---

*Use*

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    for (String s : Arrays.asList("(4,3)", "4 3", "4,3", "d 3", "d3", "D3")) {
        int[] xy = parseToCoord(s);
        System.out.println(xy[0] + " " + xy[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a clever way of doing it as each digit is only going to be one char long. Keep in mind the capital 'A' and lowercase 'a' share different number codes when they are made ints, so it might not work well without checking its case correctly.

Comment: @BallisticBlaze that's why there is a `.toLowerCase()` before the split, to ensure that we have  lower caser letters ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to implement the solution. The input is validated and the program throws appropriate exception. I think some or most aspects of this code can be used in implementing a solution.

The program is run from command prompt as follows, for example:

```
> java CoordinateParser "d 7"
```

**The example's code**:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CoordinateParser {

    private static final Map<Character, Integer> charIntMap = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        charIntMap.put('a', 0);
        charIntMap.put('b', 1);
        charIntMap.put('c', 2);
        charIntMap.put('d', 3);
        charIntMap.put('e', 4);
        charIntMap.put('f', 5);
        charIntMap.put('g', 6);
        charIntMap.put('h', 7);
        charIntMap.put('i', 8);
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Program needs input string argument, for example:");
            System.out.println("java CoordinateParser \"d7\"");
            System.out.println("Exiting the program.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Input: " + args[0]);

        XYCoordinates xy = new CoordinateParser().getCoordinates(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Co-ordinates: " + xy);
    }

    private XYCoordinates getCoordinates(String input)
            throws NumberFormatException {

        input = input.trim();

        if (input.length() < 2 || input.length() > 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input string length: " + input);
        }

        if (input.length() == 5 && input.startsWith("(") && input.endsWith(")")) {
            return new XYCoordinates(input.substring(1, 2), input.substring(3, 4));
        }

        if (input.length() == 3 && input.contains(",")) {
            return new XYCoordinates(input.substring(0, 1), input.substring(2, 3));
        }       

        if (input.length() == 3 && input.contains(" ")) {
            String x = input.substring(0, 1);
            Integer i = charIntMap.get(x.charAt(0));
            if (i != null) {
                return new XYCoordinates(Integer.toString(i), input.substring(2, 3));
            }
        }           

        if (input.length() == 2) {
            String x = input.substring(0, 1);
            Integer i = charIntMap.get(x.charAt(0));
            if (i != null) {
                return new XYCoordinates(Integer.toString(i), input.substring(1, 2));
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input format: " + input);
    }

    /*
     * Inner class represents x and y co-ordinates.
     */
    private class XYCoordinates {

        private int x;
        private int y;

        XYCoordinates(String xStr, String yStr) 
                throws NumberFormatException {

            try {
                x = Integer.parseInt(xStr);
                y = Integer.parseInt(yStr);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid co-ordinates: " +
                    new StringJoiner(", ", "(", ")")
                        .add(xStr).add(yStr).toString());
            }

            if (isNotValidValue(x) || isNotValidValue(y)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Co-ordinates out of range: " + toString());
            }
        }

        private boolean isNotValidValue(int i) {
            return (i < 0 || i > 8);
        }

        int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringJoiner(", ", "(", ")")
                .add(Integer.toString(x))
                .add(Integer.toString(y))
                .toString();
        }
    }
}
```

**XYCoordintes class**:

A POJO (Plain Old Java Object) represents an object, in this case, defined by the class `XYCoordinates` (has a set of co-ordinates `x` and `y`). Advantages of having a POJO are:

- One can retrieve the individual co-ordinates easily; for example,
  `getX()` and `getY()`.
- Get a string representation of the co-ordinates - by overriding the
  `toString` method inherited from the `java.lang.Object`.
- Compare two co-ordinates are same (or equal) by overriding the
  `Object` class's `equals` method (two sets of co-ordinates with same `x`
  and `y` values might be considered equal).
- Store some co-ordinates in a collection and retrieve them efficiently
  (overriding the `Object` class's `hashcode` method can help).

These are some of the advantages. Also, other attributes or behavior can be defined for the POJO class as needed; comparing two co-ordinates and sorting a collection of co-ordinates comes to mind (remember the `Comparable` and `Comparator` functional interfaces).

Comment: You're solution is correct, but a bit huge for a quite simple problem, you might think about "minimalist" adjective when you're writing code, because if not, when the problem will be bigger you're going to write hundreds of line when a dozen will be sufficient. Example you write about 120 lines when my solution is less than 5. But good job this is very good ;)

Comment: @azro Thanks for the comments. I think this is not a complete solution - it has features that can be part of solution. For example, the `XYCoordinates` class - this validates and stores the X and Y co-ordinates (note: storing is a requirement and using a class for that is oo programming). Then there is validation of input and possible formats - important in any application. _Continued in the following comment..._

Comment: Further, the code can be reduced by using some things like this in the `getCoordinates` method: `return new XYCoordinates(input.substring(1, 2), input.substring(3, 4));` and avoiding `x` and `y` local variables. Finally, its not number of lines that makes a working program - its readability, maintainability, enhaceabilty and the ability to understand (note that "I am somewhat new to java...").

Comment: Edited the program for some refinements in code (logic remains the same).